# " can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory " Getting this error when i am trying to runserver localhost

Tags: django, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

whenever i try to runserver i get this error in Django.

here is my shell commands:

```
C:\Users\Prozzzz\Django_projects> Django-admin startproject Django_projects
C:\Users\Prozzzz\Django_projects> python manage.py runserver
C:\Users\Prozzzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Make sure you are in the directory that contains manage.py when you run that command.

Comment: it seems you are not in project directory. Please navigate to project directory and then run `python manage.py runserver `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[startproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#startproject)

> `django-admin startproject name [directory]`
>
> Creates a Django project directory structure for the given project name in the current directory or the given destination.
>
> By default, the new directory contains manage.py and a project package (containing a settings.py and other files). See the template source for details.

As the commenters have pointed out, you need to be in the directory containing the `manage.py` file to run the command: `$ python manage.py runserver`

The Django provided `startproject` command (without the directory parameter) will create a directory in your current working directory that contains the necessary `manage.py` file. Therefore, you need to change directories (`cd`) into the `./Django_projects` directory, then your command will work.

Alternatively, you could pass in the `.` directory parameter to instantiate the project in your current working directory.